# Which is the correct tashahhud in prayer?

Tags: salat

In the part where we do the tashahhud and raise the right hand index finger, which saying is correct (A) or (B)? :

(A) Ash-hadu an laa ilaaha ill-Allaah wa ash-hadu anna Muhammadan rasooluh Allah

(B) Ash-hadu an laa ilaaha ill-Allaah wa ash-hadu anna Muhammadan ‘abduhu wa rasooluh

I always said it as (A) since I was young and I still do. 
But on the internet people say it as (B).
Have I been saying it wrong? Does that mean all my prayers have been invalid?

Comment: Why should there be a right or wrong when both are similar in the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

B is right. I study it in prayer book (Nemaz).Allah for give sins it is a mistake. Don't worry and  Do it right now .
Allaho Ghafoor o Raheem.

Comment: Provide an evidence to make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Tashahhud:
أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لاَ إِلٰهَ إِلاّ الله وَ أَشَهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّداً عَبْدُهُ وَ رَسُولُه، أَللّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلىٰ مُحَمَّدٍ وَ آلِ مُحَمَّد.

I bear witness that there is no god but Allah and Muhammad is His servant and Messenger.O Allah! Send blessings on Muhammad and his progeny.

> Among the obligatory parts of prayer is tashahhud which is recited in
> the second and last rak‘ahs of prayer. In the tashahhud we testify and
> bear witness to the Oneness of Allah and the apostleship {risalah} of
> His Prophet, Hadrat Muhammad (S). Although we have testified again and
> again to these two facts in the adhan and iqamah, those testimonies
> were at the time of the approach of the prayer and this testimony is
> at the end of the prayer.
>
> There is wisdom behind all these repetitions. It is because man is
> easily subjected to negligence and forgetfulness, easily forgetting
> the Owner of the blessings. These sentences are like a rope that
> protects the ship of humanity from the waves of events.

Reference: https://www.al-islam.org/commentary-prayer-professor-muhsin-qaraati/tashahhud-and-salam